# how to execute 2 async functions in sequence without blocking execution

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to run 2 function asynchronously, one after another, but at the same not block code execution that follows. This is my code:

```
def someFunction:

    dataFromCallingContext = "data created in the calling function"
    alsoDataFromCallingContext = "also data created in the calling function"

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncCode = asyncio.gather(Gateway.delete_gateways(dataFromCallingContext), Gateway.set_status_for_index("available", alsoDataFromCallingContext ))
    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncCode)
    loop.close()
    #run the code below immediately and do not wait for gather to finish
```

The code deletes what is represented as gateway, and after it is done, it sets the status "available" to the correct flag. `Gateway.delete_gateways` takes a very long time

If run, this returns an error saying that `'Gateway.delete_gateways' and also 'Gateway.set_status_for_index' was never awaited`, but I do not want it to be awaited. I want the code that follows to continue executing without blocking. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: You can make a new async function that awaits for the first to finish before running the second. Then run it as a task.

Comment: by in sequence do you mean you want `Gateway.delete_gateways()` to finish before calling `Gateway.set_status_for_index()`?

Comment: @rcshon That is correct.

Comment: and `Gateway` is a class not an instance right?

Comment: @rcshon I think your proposition would work. Although I am not very excited about it because both `Gateway.delete_gateways()` and `Gateway.set_status_for_index()` expect parameters that are set in the calling context. It would uglify the functions a bit if I were to chain the data in one function just to pass it to another. But hey, this is not a beauty pageant.

Comment: @rcshon Gateway is a class

Comment: what is this "calling context" you mention?

Comment: I edited the code with an example

Comment: I still don't understand. So they are separate instance of different data?

Comment: its just the variables calculated in the calling function that are passed to the called functions as arguments

Comment: so they are data structures passed to the functions to modify? and they are separate instances?

Comment: literally just strings

Comment: @rcshon hmm. Even making a new async function that awaits for the first to finish before running the second is not working, because the new function is never executed, I assume because the calling function(see example) is not async

Comment: @sanjihan please update your question with the code you have tried to make it work.